# How to show browse button in custom OleDB driver

Tags: c++, com, oledb, atl

I am writing a custom OleDB provider using ATL. It connects to a file-type database. The driver functionality is complete, except for one omission.

In the Data Link properties dialog for the driver, the user has to manually type in (or paste) the required filename in to the DataSource edit box. I would like it to have a browse button for the file, as the MS Jet OleDB driver does. Is it a DBPROP structure that provides this functionality, where you can specify that you want to allow the user to browse, and also the file extension filter?

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample provider that prompts for a path, maybe it helps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715011(v=VS.85).aspx